# Print all in once

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

The code that I provided below prints the output one line at a time. However, I want to rewrite the code to print all the content all together at once.

```
def filters():
            for LogLine in Log:
                flag = True
                for key,ConfLine in Conf.items():
                    for patterns in ConfLine:
                        print patterns
                        if re.match((DateString + patterns), LogLine):
                            flag = False
                            break 

                    if(flag == False):
                        break 

                if(flag):

                print LogLine
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one thing that I would do. I would initialize an empty dictionary or empty list and then append all the items to the empty dictionary or empty list. Finally print the output all together at once.

```
def filters():
    mypatterns=[]
    for LogLine in Log:
        flag = True
        for key,ConfLine in Conf.items():
            for patterns in ConfLine:
                print patterns
                mypatterns.append(patterns)
                if re.match((DateString + patterns), LogLine):
                    flag = False
                    break
            if(flag == False):
                break
        if(flag):
            print LogLine

print mypatterns
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the general technique:

```
lines = []
for ...
    lines.append(<whatever you were going to print>)
print '\n'.join(lines)
```